# How do I make the width/length of a form field longer using CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a form field box with class CCPPDisplayTD.

I'm trying to make it's length longer with CSS styling.

How do I use CSS to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

```
<form>
    <input type="text" /><br />
    <input type="text" class="CCPPDisplayTD" />
</form>


.CCPPDisplayTD{
    width: 200px;
}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/GT8jD/

Answer (score 1):

In your stylehseet you need the following:

```
.CCPPDisplayTD{
    width: 250px; // whatever size you need.
}
```

Your HTML needs to resemble something similar to:

```
<form>
    <label> /* Label elements are required for better accessibility */
        <input type="text" class="CCPPDisplayTD" />
    </label>
</form>
```

Or the following:

```
<form>
    <label for="input-name"> /* Label elements are required for better accessibility */
        <input type="text" class="CCPPDisplayTD" id="input-name" name="input-name"  />
    </label>
</form>
```